# How to share PDF along with text in Whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp

I can send either the PDF file or the text but not both in Whatsapp. Please guide on how to send text and PDF at the same time.

Comment: Can you tell briefly, do u want to share pdf and text to  Whatsapp?

Comment: Yes , PDF file with some text along with it.